# "make package install" error - theos ios 8.4

Tags: theos, ios8.4

I'm trying to create an app with Theos on my iPhone 6, but when I type "make package install" in MobileTerminal, it always says the same error:

`theos/makefiles/common.mk:115: *** The "iphone" target is not supported on the "" platform. Stop.`

I used "Theos Tutorials" by ReverseEffect, and it shows that error every time no matter what I do. I have iOS 8.1 sdks downloaded and I'm running iOS 8.4 on the TaiG jailbreak.

Here is my makefile:

```
include theos/makefiles/common.mk

APPLICATION_NAME = Hello
Hello_FILES = main.m HelloApplication.mm RootViewController.mm
Hello_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit Foundation

include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/application.mk
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands:

```
sudo ln -s $THEOS/makefiles/platform/Darwin-arm{,64}.mk
sudo ln -s $THEOS/makefiles/targets/Darwin-arm{,64}
```

See common issues on the wiki:
http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Setup#Undefined_platform

Answer (score 0):

In your make file add this to the top

```
ARCHS = armv7 arm64
```